# PnP search result WebPart syntax to split Url and get document Breadcrumb

Tags: web-part, search, pnp, web

I'm trying to display document breadcrumb on PnP search results by adapting the code from Search Result WebPart:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    {{# each (after (split (after Path (length SPSiteUrl)) '/') 2)}}
        {{#unless @last}}
            {{#unless @first}}
                <i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ChevronRight" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            {{/unless}}
            {{#*inline "nodeUrl"}}{{> caseSafeSiteUrl ..}}/{{join (first (after (split (after ../Path (length ../SPSiteUrl)) '/') 1) (add @index 2)) '/'}}{{/inline}}
            <li class="breadcrumbNode">
                <a href="{{> nodeUrl}}" title={{this}} target="_blank" data-interception="off">{{capitalize this}}</a>
            </li>
        {{/unless}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

I tried this code without success:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <span>
        <a href="{{slot item @root.slots.Path}}">
            {{slot item @root.slots.Title}}
        </a> 
        {{#with (split {{slot item @root.slots.Path}} {{slot item @root.slots.Filename}}) as |{{slot item @root.slots.filelocation}}}}
            {{#eq (last (split (dirname {{slot item @root.slots.filelocation}}) "/")) 'SitePages'}}
            {{else}}
                > <a href="{{dirname slot item @root.slots.filelocation}}">
                    {{last (split (dirname {{slot item @root.slots.filelocation}}) "/")}}
                </a>
            {{/eq}}
        {{/with}}                           
    </span>
</ul>
```

Any help is appreciated.